# Ping from browser

Tags: html, ping

I have an HTML page which I want to test a ping from.
I want a user to connect to the website and in the main page he will get a result of the round trip from his computer to a specific server.

Should I use "Ping"?
I heard about something called applicable ping but it's something that I need to build myself and I don't know how..
Please help

Comment: You cannot ping from a browser.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Are you looking to calculate the round-trip time of a connection from the client to the server?

Comment: The popular "ping" refers to basic ICMP comunication, you are not capable of doing that with pure HTML/JS. You will either have to use some form of TCP Ping with AJAX or rely on third-party methods like Macromedia Flash to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Ping is just the measure of delay between a request and response. Though ping is realybased on ICMP as stated by Havenard, you can simulate this using HTML/JS but it will add a bit of delay because of processing in the high levels.

---

`ping-server.html` (Server side)

```
hello
```

---

`ping-client.html` (Client side/In the browser using jQuery/js)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ping = new Date;

    $.ajax({
        url: "ping-server.html",
        cache:false,
        success: function(output){ 
            ping = new Date - ping;
            Console.log("Ping/Latency: " + ping);
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

## [JSFiddle Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/e7s86a2y/1/)

Comment: its wrong answer I guess, you are just getting the distance time between loading data from server. So its not the ping, it is response time.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

I didn't make this. It seems to do what you're asking for, if you want to add your own server just add it to

```
var komodel = new PingModel(['localhost',
'ws-bdimperio8',
'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.net',
'ws-bdimperio8.payformance.com',
'ws-bdimperio8.payspan.com',
'ws-bdimperio8/favicon.ico',
'127.0.0.1', 
'unknown'
]);
```

Comment: whats the PingModel?